# Why can`t I put a zero in front of an integer in an "if" statement

Tags: c++

Why does my little cheat code not work when I put the zero in front of it. When I take the zero out and put the little cheat code in it works just fine. However, when I put the zero in and use the cheat code - it will skip right over.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    bool correct = false;
    std::cout << "Put a Number from 1 to 100" << std::endl;
    int guess = 0;
    std::cin >> guess;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rnd(0, 101);
    int answer = rnd(mt); //random number
    while (correct == false)
    {
        if (guess == answer)
        {
            std::cout<<"You got it!!!"<<std::endl;
            correct = true;
        }
        else if (guess == 01010101)#<--------------------Problem
        #it works when it is 1010101
        {
            std::cout<< answer<< std::endl;
            std::cout << "Put a Number from 1 to 100" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> guess;
        }
        else if (guess > answer)
        {
            std::cout<<"Your guess is to high guess again"<< std::endl;
            std::cout << "Put a Number from 1 to 100" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> guess;
        }
        else if (guess < answer)
        {
            std::cout<<"Your guess is to low guess again"<< std::endl;
            std::cout << "Put a Number from 1 to 100" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> guess;
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout << "Put a Number from 1 to 100" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> guess;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal. Specifically a
decimal-literal is a non-zero decimal digit (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), followed by zero or more decimal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), whereas an octal-literal is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7).

Comment: `while (correct == false)` is more clearly written as `while (! correct)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A leading zero on a numeric literal indicates that the literal is expressed in [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8) notation<sup>1</sup>, which (obviously) has a different magnitude than the same digits interpreted as decimal (base 10).

The octal number 01010101 is equal to the decimal number 266305.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless the leading zero is followed by an `x`, then it's interpreted as hexadecimal (base 16).

Comment: or a `b`, in which case it is binary. If you see 0ж1010101, I'm not sure what base that is, but I would advise that you stop playing around with old Soviet code and go get some real software.

Comment: 01010101 should be 266305 in decimal number.

Comment: Check your octal math.

Comment: @JimMa Ugh, you are right. I went decimal->octal because potato.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Since C++14, anyway. Before then it was a compiler-specific extension.